# C Why can't my fgets() read line properly when writing with \n after words

Tags: c

This is a bit difficult to articulate but what I would like is for my commented out fprintf function to be commented in and my other two print functions commented out (In my add_to_white_list function).

However, when I write to the file in that way (with the \n after the word) something goes wrong with my fgets line reader in the remove_from_white_list function. In debugging my fgets reads the first line and then seems to be blank after.

This if very confusing to me because everything mostly works as is and there are still newline characters after all my words except for the last word in the file.

```
void add_to_white_list(char* ip) {
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("../app/whitelist.txt", "r+");

  if (!(getc(fp) < 0)) {
    fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END);
    fputs("\n", fp);
  }

  fprintf(fp, "%s", ip);
  //fprintf(fp, "%s\n", ip);

  fclose(fp);
}

void remove_from_white_list(char* ip) {
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *fp_temp;
  fp = fopen("../app/whitelist.txt", "r");
  fp_temp = fopen("../app/temp.txt", "w+");

  char buff[255];
  int matched = 0;

  while (fgets(buff, 255, fp) != NULL) {
    strip(buff);
    if (!(strcmp(buff, ip) == 0)) {
        fprintf(fp_temp, "%s\n", buff);
    } else {
      matched = 1;
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
  fclose(fp_temp);

  if (matched == 0) {
    printf("Please supply an ip address that is currently listed on the whitelist\n");
  } else {
    rename("../app/temp.txt", "../app/whitelist.txt");
  }
}
```

*I didn't include my strip function but it removes \n

Comment: "This is a bit difficult to articulate". Please provide a [mcve] including *exact* input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549718/behaviour-of-fseek-and-seek-end). And be sure to add the `strip` function to your question. It's silly to tell us that you're having problems with newlines, and then not show us a function that deals with newlines.

Answer (score 2):

This may not fix your problem but you can simplify `add_to_white_list` to:

```
void add_to_white_list(char* ip) {
   FILE *fp = fopen("../app/whitelist.txt", "a");
   if ( fp != NULL )
   {
      fprintf(fp, "%s\n", ip);
      fclose(fp);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the append mode "a" is exactly what I was trying to do in the first place.  I was creating my own append mode.  Seems to of fixed the problem as well!